# Default expiry time for HttpRuntime cache

Tags: httpruntime.cache

I know you can give specific expiry time by using `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Add()` but I'm curious what the default expiry time is when you add a cache item by doing `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["a"] = "b"`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I take my question back :) Apparently it's noAbsoluteExpiration